# A dictionary of keys and lists as their values. How to identify item in the list, and move to another list? (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In my comp sci class, we've just touched on dictionaries. I'm trying to figure out how to remove an item from a list in a dictionary and move it to another list.

For example,

```
dict1={ 'colors':[red,blue,green], 'sweaters':[mine, his, hers]}
```

Let's say I wanted to check if "red" was in the dictionary, and it was. So how could I go about removing it from "colors", and adding it to "sweaters"? The list part has thrown me off.

This is the function I have thus far( the actual problem)

`def nowRead(yourDict, title):

```
key1, key2, key3, key4 = yourDict.values() 
if title in key2: 
    key2.remove(title)
    key3.append(title)
return yourDict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    if 'red' in dict1[key]:
        theList = dict1[key]
        # remove 'red' from theList
        # append 'red' to another list in dict1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know (a) how to access an object in a dictionary; and (b) how to add something to a list? Those are the operations you need here.

You'll also need to figure out how to delete from a list, but the above will take you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "red" in d["colors"]:
    d["colors"].remove("red")
    d["sweaters"].append("red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
colorsToLook = ['red']
dVals = { 'colors': ['red','blue','green'], 'sweaters':['mine', 'his', 'hers']}

for k in set(colorsToLook):
    if k in dVals['colors']:
        dVals['sweaters'].append(dVals['colors'].pop(dVals['colors'].index(k)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like

```
dict1['colors'].remove('red')
dict1['sweaters'].append('red')
```

More lists methonds you can find in [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Also, if you are interested in using Python, [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) is a great start.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1={ 'colors':['red','blue','green'], 'sweaters':['mine', 'his', 'hers']}

def change_lists(target):
    try:
        dict1['colors'].remove(target)
        dict1['sweaters'].append(target)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Result:

```
>>> dict1
{'colors': ['red', 'blue', 'green'], 'sweaters': ['mine', 'his', 'hers']}
>>> change_lists('red')
>>> dict1
{'colors': ['blue', 'green'], 'sweaters': ['mine', 'his', 'hers', 'red']}
>>> change_lists('black')
>>> dict1
{'colors': ['blue', 'green'], 'sweaters': ['mine', 'his', 'hers', 'red']}
```